# Store user data in CANNON.Body for later use?

Tags: javascript, cannon.js

Is it possible to store user data in a `CANNON.Body` object for later use? For example:

```
var ballBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
ballBody.userData = { name: 'tester' };
// ...
world.add(ballBody);

// ...
player.addEventListener('collide', function(e) {
    console.log(e.contact.bi.userData.name); // ==> tester
});
```

Comment: [Github Issue](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/issues/156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The information is saved and kept in `e.body.userData` in the `collide` event.